# How to define Getter and Setter (Property) in java interface

Tags: java

I want to use RMI in my application. So using the interface is compulsory. I want to force the developer to implement getter and setters. So I want to define the getter and setter methods in my interface. How can I do this? Unfortunately there is no useful article or link to help me. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: From the looks of things you haven't done any research. Try looking up how to create get and set functions, and also how to make interfaces.

Comment: can't you use abstract class ?

Comment: define setters and getters the same way you do in class,but the variables in interface will be `public static final` by default

Comment: you should not have getters and setters in interface. You're spoiling its beauty.

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface MyInterface {
    PropertyType getProperty();
    void setProperty(PropertyType property);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can `declare` method in interface, you can not `define` it's body inside it.

> Interfaces form a contract between the class and the outside world,
>   and this contract is enforced at build time by the compiler. If your
>   class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that
>   interface must appear in its source code before the class will
>   successfully compile.

It will be defined where that `interface` will be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have inbuilt support for get-set properties.You have define your own get-set properties like

```
int getCount();
void setValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

write your methods without body

```
public interface MyInteface {
    public String getSomething();
    public void setSomething(String str);
}
```

then any class that implements this interface has to implements these get/set methods

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the getter and setter in the interface any reasonable IDE will tell you that you have to implement them in a class that implements the interface. Even if the IDE does not tell you that, java will print out an error that is reasonable enough and easy to understand. Little room for error there.